# so many values in my DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I have **4,000,000** rows in a table in my db how i can take them `100 by 100`?

Comment: Describe more and try to post some tryout code.

Comment: what you want to get group  of every 100 rows . or only 100 rows where condition matches

Comment: a group of 100... I did it with limit but it takes alway the same values

Comment: You have to use `OFFSET`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: `limit 0,100` then  `limit 101 ,200` etc.

Comment: search for php pagination otherwise paste the codes you tried.

Comment: http://papermashup.com/demos/php-pagination/

Comment: I want only the msql code not all this things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 0,100
```

and next call

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 100,100
```

and then

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 200,100
```

And, of course, don't repeat your query in code 10 000 times, but put it in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL Server* you can use [OFFSET FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

In following example It will select 100 rows starting from 0 (1-100). If you want to select next 100 rows (101-200) you can change to `OFFSET 100` and etc.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: it will run untill 200... no?

Comment: `OFFSET 0` will return `1-100` rows, `OFFSET 100` will return `101-200` rows, `OFFSET 200` will return `201-300` rows and etc.

Comment: yeah i know but there i have 0

Comment: What you have 0? Explain more.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged with Drupal, I will assume you want a drupal answer.
You could use the function [db_query_range](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query_range/7).
eg.

```
$result = db_query_range('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
  FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = :uid
  ORDER BY n.created DESC', 0, 100, array(':uid' => $uid));
foreach ($result as $record) {
  // Perform operations on $record->title, etc. here.
}
```